# what is the best way to find substring in a string with its frequency using c#?

Tags: c#, substring, frequency

I am trying to find a word in a string which means

if `abcdef ghijk` is a string then substring `ghijk` should give us 1 as frequency. 
but if substring is `cde` then 0 should be returned.

i wish this was possible with Regex but I don't know if it is. or may be there is a method in string class.

Comment: Why would `cde` return 0? Do you want the word frequency?

Comment: @alexn, seems to be so.

Comment: @alexn yes i want the word frequency only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to find only whole words within the string. This can be accomplished with a regular expression using `\b`, which means 'word boundary'. For example:

```
var input = "abcdef ghijk";

var freq1 = Regex.Matches(input, @"\bghijk\b").Count;
Console.WriteLine(freq1); // 1

var freq2 = Regex.Matches(input, @"\bcde\b").Count;
Console.WriteLine(freq2); // 0
```

This will also take into account punctuation like commas and periods.

Answer (score 5):

If you want words frequency, you can create word freq. dictionary like this:

```
s.Split().GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count())
```

And then check if word in this dictionary.

```
var s = "abcdef ghijk abcdef";
var d = s.Split().GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count())
// Dictionary<string, int>(2) { { "abcdef", 2 }, { "ghijk", 1 } }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
int frequency = YourString.Split().Where(a => a == subString).Count();
```

it will give the frequency otherwise zero.